# Dulplication of messages in group chatting project in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I want to send group messages but when I am sending it first time its working fine but after when I  received it, it occurs duplication of the messages. Number of duplication of sending messages is equal to number of received messages. 
I tried to use Message Connection for sending message.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue.

The best solution for such is to give your messages an id value before sending them. You could encode in JSON.
Then check for the existence of the message id (if it doesnt exist) before storing/rendering the message.